# SVG, Text does not render on textPath when I create it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, svg

I want to create a textPath dynamically, so I wrote this:

```
function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
        var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
        for (var k in attrs)
            el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
        return el;
    }

    function appendSVG(item, tag, attrs) {
        var el = document.getElementById(item);
        el.appendChild(makeSVG(tag, attrs));
    }

    function TEST() {
        appendSVG('pannel', 'path', {'id':'PID', 'd': 'M 0 0 L 100 100', 'stroke': '#000000' })
        appendSVG('pannel', 'text', { 'id': 'TID', 'x': '5', 'fill': '#000000' })
        appendSVG('TID', 'textPath', { 'xlink:href': '#PID', 'id':'TPath' })
        $('#TPath').append('TEXT');
    }
```

I have an SVG element "panel" on the page.
The problem is - it doesnt work

The same code written in an html file works correctly.

You can see the example of what I'm talking [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qpIlIpp/2agebmq1/1/)

(Pressing the "test" button creates the same svg as on the top (except ids =) ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use setAttribute to create an attribute in a non-null namespace but that's precisely what you are trying to do when creating the xlink:href attribute.

The xlink:href attribute must be created via setAttributeNS i.e.

```
el.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', attrs[k]);
```